# how to update with limit(1) in mongomapper?

Tags: mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3.2, mongomapper

i have a problem for a simple select and update logic :

```
task = Task.queueing.where(conditions).order(:created_at.asc).first
if task
  task.set(:status=>2)
end
```

it's simple right ?

BUT, the problem is : 100+ requests coming in the same time have.
SO many client got the same record, that's what i DONT want.

in mysql, i can do some thing like this to avoid duplicate load:

```
rnd_str = 10000000 * rand
Task.update(status:rnd_str).limit(1) # this may be wrong code
task = Task.where(status:rnd_str).first
task.set(status:2)
render :json=>task
```

BUT HOW TO UPDATE 1 RECORD WITH QUERY IN mongomapper ?

thx !

Comment: FIXED : 
thanks @asya-kamsky , following your idea, i found a usfull page for me: http://jottingsoncomputation.blogspot.com/2012/08/adding-findandmodify-to-mongomapper-and.html
a simple plugin to support findandmodify command in mongomapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An update in MongoDB will only update one record by default.  You have an option to update all the matching documents in a query [with `{multi:true}` option](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/update/#update-multiple-documents) but by default your update will only update *one* document.

So what you have to do is combine your "query" into your update statement so they execute atomically (just like you do it in SQL) and not do two separate operations.  In shell syntax, something like:

```
   db.queueing.update({conditions}, {$set:{status:2}})
```

Now, if you also need the task document you updated to work with then you can use [findAndModify](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/) to update and return the document in one atomic operation.  Like this:

```
   task = db.queueing.findAndModify( {your-condition}, 
                                     sort: { your-ordering },
                                     update: { $set: { status: 2 } }
          } );
```